# How to check user type after login ? DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I have two user types in my application. How do I check user type after login? My login view extends django's LoginView. In my Login View, i tried with form_valid, but I think it does validation before authentication.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_supermarket = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py

```
class LoginView(LoginView):
    
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #check if the user is logged in and redirect to home page
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('produtos:home')
        return super(LoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Have you tried `request.user.is_client` or `request.user.is_supermarket`?

Comment: Yes, but it always returns anonymous user

Comment: use [**`@login_required(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)

Comment: So I want everyone to have access to LoginView. However, if is_supermaket tries to login, access is denied. Supermaket will have a unique login page for it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom decoration for this. The decoration will redirect users to the page you give to the decorator. If you don't give anything the default is `home`

```
def client_required(request, redirect_name='home'):
    if not request.user.is_client:
        return redirect(redirect_name)


# e.g.: @client_required(request, 'supermarket:login')

@client_required(request)  
class LoginView(LoginView):


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #check if the user is logged in and redirect to home page
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('produtos:home')
        return super(LoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

or

```
class LoginView(LoginView):
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #check if the user is logged in and redirect to home page
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('produtos:home')
        if request.user.is_supermarket:
            return redirect('supermarket-login') #your unique login page for supermarket user
        return super(LoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: No, I don't want to allow users with the is_supermaket flag to be able to login in LoginView. Because both will have their login page.

Comment: @xSkolz I have updated my answer please check this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best approach, but I get the expected behavior

```
class LoginView(LoginView):
        
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('produtos:home')
        return super(LoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.get_user().is_supermarket:
            self.request.session.flush()
            logout(self.request)
            return redirect('login')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```